# Rails reverse proxied by Nginx: change of origin problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx-reverse-proxy

I reverse proxied a full stack Rails app (port:3000) with Nginx(port:8080). Without Nginx, localhost:3000 works (I can `get, post, patch, delete`s). On localhost:8080, I can only `get` but I can't `post, delete, patch`. For example, an ajaxified 'update' method uses this snippet:

```js
import { csrfToken } from "@rails/ujs";
const postGenreToResto = async (obj = {}) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/updateGenre", {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken(),
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    });
    return await response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
export { postGenreToResto };
```

and my error is:

```
Started PATCH "/updateGenre" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-10-07 17:04:04 +0200
Processing by RestosController#updateGenre as JSON
  Parameters: {Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"s+bpdFxhy2Sr...","genre_id"=>"7", "id"=>"1", "resto"=>{"id"=>"1", "genre_id"=>"7"}}
HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:8080) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost)
Completed 500  in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1787)
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

The `csrf-token` is ok. Could it be an Nginx settings problem, especially the headers?

---- EDITED ---

With the modified `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file below, it works. On localhost, when the service Nginx is running and listening to port:8080, I can post/patch/delete just like on localhost:3000 which Rails serves. I pushed this config on Heroku with a buildpack and it works as well.

The Nginx docs are not so easy to read and I am not sure I really understood what I did :)

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0; # version tcp/ip <=> port
    } 
    
    server {
       listen 8080;
       location / {
          try_files $uri @rails;  
       }
       location @rails {    
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;   
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          ##proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port; 
          ## proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header  Host $http_host; 
          proxy_redirect    off;    
          proxy_pass        http://app_server;  
       }
```

Comment: Answering your own question is very common, but since you edited your question instead of writing an answer, it's not showing as an answered question, and you're not getting credit for it.

Comment: Not sure how this worked. I couldn't make it work until I rewrote the `Origin` header conditionally. Similar to how I describe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649620/520567. Condition is only when `$http_origin = $scheme://$host`.