# nginx reverse-proxy rewriting custom header (NOT URL)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I am trying to rewrite custom header information like "Author" (not part of the URL) using nginx reverse proxy.
The header information "Author:" should be rewritten from "test123" to e.g. "BASIC"

**command:**

admin1@nginx1:~$ `curl -x 192.168.175.134:80 http://home1.MyWeb.eu:8081/home1/index.html?t=1  -H "Author: test123" -vk`

**TCPdump on apache:**

```
--
GET /home1/index.html?t=1 HTTP/1.0
Host: home1.MyWeb.eu
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Author: test123
```

wanted result:

```
--
GET /home1/index.html?t=1 HTTP/1.0
Host: home1.MyWeb.eu
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Author: BASIC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) in your configuration. I.e.:

```
proxy_set_header            Author        "BASIC";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but unfortunately I need to change the header information based o the actual header value. In case the header is "test123" I need to change it to BASIC, in case the header value is "TEST789" I need to change is to e.g. "ADVANCED".

I have tried to work with REGEX, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made with setting variables. A little ugly but seems to work.

```
        location / {
            <...>

            set $rewritten_header $http_myheader;
            if ($http_myheader = "something") {
              set $rewritten_header somethingelse;
            }
            proxy_set_header Myheader $rewritten_header;
        }
```

The above will rewrite your header only if the condition match. Otherwise keep original value.

I think more elegant to use [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) in case you have a large mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solved the issue like this:

```
curl -x localhost:80 https://www.dummy.com -H "Authorization: test12" -vk
```

NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.2:443 ssl;
        # the included file below contains ssl certificates
    include snippets/www.dummy.com.conf;
    root /var/www/html;

set $MyAuthorization 'Basic bGaa9zX25ljYhhWxlcl9=';

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www;
                proxy_set_header Host www.dummy.com;

      proxy_set_header Authorization $MyAuthorization;
    
    }
}
```